# TCL: TCP Wrapper (tcp_wrappers.tcz) installed but /usr/local/bin/tcpd file is not there

Tags: tinycore, tcp-wrappers

I'm learning host based firewall by installing `tcp_wrappers.tcz` on Tiny Core Linux (TCL).

Initially, the following files were not there which was expected.

```
/etc/hosts.allow
/etc/hosts.deny
```

BEFORE

```
tc@linux:/etc$ date; ls -lh /etc/host*
Thu May  3 20:20:51 UTC 2018
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     staff         26 Jul  4  2016 /etc/host.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           4 May  3 20:18 /etc/hostname
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         290 May  3 20:18 /etc/hosts
```

INSTALLATION

```
tc@linux:/etc$ tce-load -wi tcp_wrappers.tcz
Downloading: tcp_wrappers.tcz
Connecting to repo.tinycorelinux.net (89.22.99.37:80)
tcp_wrappers.tcz     100% |****************************************************************************************************************************************| 40960   0:00:00 ETA
tcp_wrappers.tcz: OK
```

AFTER

```
tc@linux:/etc$ date; ls -lh /etc/host*
Thu May  3 20:21:14 UTC 2018
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     staff         26 Jul  4  2016 /etc/host.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           4 May  3 20:18 /etc/hostname
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         290 May  3 20:18 /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         121 Nov 27  2008 /etc/hosts.allow
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         119 Nov 27  2008 /etc/hosts.deny
```

Then, I was able to see both files created.

```
tc@linux:/etc$ cat /etc/hosts.allow
# hosts.allow   This file describes the names of the hosts which are allowed access by the '/usr/local/bin/tcpd' server.

tc@linux:/etc$ cat /etc/hosts.deny
# hosts.deny   This file describes the names of the hosts which are denied access by the '/usr/local/bin/tcpd' server.
```

Unfortunately, `/usr/local/bin/tcpd` was not there.

```
tc@linux:/etc$ ls -lh /usr/local/bin/tcpd
ls: /usr/local/bin/tcpd: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, TCP Wrapper won't work without `tcpd` right?

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I’ve never used Tiny Core Linux but on my Ubuntu and CentOS machines, the daemon itself is installed to `/usr/sbin/tcpd` – not `/usr/local/bin/tcpd`.  Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `command -v tcpd`?

Comment: @Sabrina: [You say](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4856/23408) that we should be more welcoming — but that’s a two-way street.  While you have described and documented your question clearly and coherently, I see no evidence that [you have “made the effort to research and solve the problem yourself.”](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4856/23408#4857)  Anthony Geoghegan [has pointed out a possible solution and asked a follow-up question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441535/23408#comment801123_441535) — and you have not responded. … It seems like you are the one turning your back.

Comment: @Scott, http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php/topic,21917.msg137160.html#msg137160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, sshd & nc were not compiled against the libwrap.a library in TCL. I've just tested `/usr/sbin/sshd` in CentOS and it works, but not in TCL.

```
[root@CentOS ~]# whereis sshd
sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd /usr/share/man/man8/sshd.8.gz
[root@CentOS ~]#

[root@CentOS ~]# ldd /usr/sbin/sshd | grep libwrap
        libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f506b6e2000)
[root@CentOS ~]#
```

http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php/topic,21917.msg137160.html#msg137160